# MySQL - Select while sum is less than x

Tags: mysql

I've got a list of cached files referenced in a database and want to purge out the oldest outside of a size limit of say 20,000,000.

Table simplistically looks like this:

```
[ hash | filesize | timestamp ]
```

At the moment just running the following command,

```
SELECT `hash`, `filesize` FROM `cachetable` ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC;
```

Then processing the results externally. Is there any way to just get a list of results outside of the 20,000,000 limit?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use OFFSET

```
SELECT `hash`, `filesize` 
FROM `cachetable` 
ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC 
LIMIT <your_limit_here> 
OFFSET 20000000;
```

be sure to replace your_limit_here with your own acceptable number.

Comment: Hey cheers, problem is though each file is a different size, I don't want to keep 20,000,000 files, but instead how ever many files that total that size

Comment: So you want to keep only X files WHERE SUM(filesize) < 20 000 000 ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) on the table, and `SUM` function to see when it crosses the threshold size, say SIZE  ( 20000000 in your case )

1. Find out size of 50% newest rows in the table.
2. If it is  less than SIZE , query for top 75% rows , if it is more than SIZE, query for top 25% rows.
3. Repeat by dividing the row set into two each time.

This way you will be able to get the target threshold within log(N) queries, where N is total rows in your table.
After getting target threshold say THRESHOLD, delete all the rows after that :

```
SELECT `hash`, `filesize` 
FROM `cachetable` 
ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC 
LIMIT  NUMBER_ROWS_TO_DELETE /* any large number to delete all after THRESHOLD */ 
OFFSET THRESHOLD;
```